# MySQL : selecting minimum value from one table and country details from another and grouping them according to country code

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my database:

```
1. venprices
+---------+---------+--------+
| concode | rate    | vendor |
+---------+---------+--------+
|    1234 | 1.23402 | a      |
|    1234 |  1.5692 | b      |
|    1234 |   1.114 | c      |
|    1234 |     1.4 | d      |
|    1122 |    1.46 | a      |
|    1122 |     1.5 | c      |
|    1122 |     1.2 | d      |
+---------+---------+--------+

2. country
+-------+---------+
| conid | conname |
+-------+---------+
|  1122 | con2    |
|  1234 | con1    |
+-------+---------+
```

I want an output like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
| concode | conname | MIN(v.rate) | vendor |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
|    1122 | con2    |         1.2 | d      |
|    1234 | con1    |       1.114 | c      |
+---------+---------+-------------+--------+
```

I am Using Query : `SELECT v.concode,c.conname, MIN(v.rate), v.vendor FROM venprices v, country c WHERE c.conid = v.concode GROUP BY c.conid;`

The query gives the result but with a wrong vendor name. Instead of delivering the rate relative vendors, it always giving me the vendor `a` in the result.

I've tried different clauses and subqueries but it went in vein.
Can someone please tell me the actual problem and the query to produce the desired result?

Comment: If you want to get to 15, it might help to see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  a suquery

```
select v.concode,c.conname, v.rate, v.vendor
FROM venprices v
inner join  country c on c.conid = v.concode 
where (v.concode, v.rate) in ( select v.concode, min(v.rate)
                                  from venprices v 
                                  group by v.concode)
```

if there isn't 'conid' related to 'concode', you can use LEFT JOIN

```
select v.concode,c.conname, v.rate, v.vendor
FROM venprices v
left join  country c on c.conid = v.concode 
where (v.concode, v.rate) in ( select v.concode, min(v.rate)
                                  from venprices v 
                                  group by v.concode)
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge. It works fine. But if there is no 'conid' related to 'concode', the result must have a blank 'conname'. What modifications will needed for that?

Comment: @ArpitPorwal I have update the answer with no 'conid' related to 'concode',

Comment: Thanks a ton @scaisEdge. You are a life saver. :) Kindly upvote the question if you enjoyed answering it. :)

Comment: @ArpitPorwal   Question  upvote .. if you have privilege you could upvate  the answer too

Comment: I am at Reputation 13 so unable to upvote. Will surely upvote after reaching 15.

Comment: I was wondering what will happen if I replace Left join with Inner Join?

Comment: @ArpitPorwal  using left join with the sample you  proposed .. It should not change anything.. in this case if you have rows that don't match you should obtain also the key related with null ... However, in SQL there is a magic word ... try .... and see what happens .. I have learned a lot of things this way

Answer (score 0):

First, never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax with the join condition in the `ON` clause.

There are several ways to accomplish what you want.  One trick uses `substring_index()` and `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT c.conid, c.conname,
       MIN(v.rate),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(v.vendor ORDER BY v.rate ASC), ',', 1) as vendor
FROM venprices v JOIN
     country c
     ON c.conid = v.concode
GROUP BY c.conid;
```

This doesn't work under all circumstances -- `group_concat()` has an intermediate string length of 1024 (which can be changed), but it often works correctly for real world data.

Comment: the query returns an error : **Error Code : 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'**